# Outputting data of a CSV using hash

Tags: ruby, csv, hash

When I have a csv file that looks like this:

```
make,model,color,doors,email
dodge,charger,black,4,practice1@whatever.com
ford,focus,blue,5,practice2@whatever.com
nissan,350z,black,2,practice3@whatever.com
mazda,miata,white,2,practice4@whatever.com
honda,civid,brown,4,practice5@whatever.com
corvette,stingray,red,2,practice6@whatever.com
ford,fiesta,blue,5,practice7@whatever.com
bmw,m4,black,2,practice8@whatever.com
audi,a5,blue,2,practice9@whatever.com
subaru,brz,black,2,practice10@whatever.com
lexus,rc,black,2,practice11@whatever.com
```

when I try to run my code I keep getting this error,

```
data [:model]
^^^^
```

I suppose this does not work like this but I was wondering if there is a way to make this work. I am just trying to let the program output all the different models. This is my code:

```
require "csv"

CSV.foreach("cars.csv", headers: true) do |row|
    data = puts row.to_h
end

data [:model]
puts data
```

I get my csv file and then turn it into a hash and make it equal to `data`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your data variable is not defined outside the loop and there is an additional space. To create a hash of hashes(lines).

One option could be to include the index using `with_index` and use it to fill the empty hash that you create before:

```
require "csv"

data = {}

CSV.foreach("cars.csv", headers: true).with_index  do |row, i|
    data[i] = row.to_h
end

pp data
```

Result:

```
{0=>
  {"make"=>"dodge",
   "model"=>"charger",
   "color"=>"black",
   "doors"=>"4",
   "email"=>"practice1@whatever.com"},
 ... ,
 ... ,
 ... ,
 10=>
  {"make"=>"lexus",
   "model"=>"rc",
   "color"=>"black",
   "doors"=>"2",
   "email"=>"practice11@whatever.com"}}
```

Another option for grouping data is to read the CSV file into an array, see `CSV.read` in the docs to be able to group the data as requested.

On the array, you can do:

```
data.group_by { |d| d[:model] }
```